# HorizontalListView fading edge

Tags: java, android

How do I set a fading edge for a HorizontalListView. I am currently using this code

```
HorizontalListView hlv = new HorizontalListView(contxt, null);
hlv.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
```

but this is not working. Can anyone tell me how do I resolve this?

Comment: I am assuming you are using a custom widget someone wrote, it's possible the implementation doesn't handle the fading edge.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate might solve your problem
Try
    hlv.invalidate();

Comment: can any1 please give me the solution for this?